# How to CRUD Application Users in ASP.NET MVC 5 with Scaffolding?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

From my experience, I can generate Controllers and Views for CRUD using EntityFrameWork(MVC 5 Controllers with Views, using EntityFramework) for Job and any other classes that are NOT derived from IdentityUser. I want to have a feature in my application where User of Role admin will be able to delete other users in the same User Table. How can I generate Controllers and Views for that using EF ? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
    public int Id JobId {get; set;}
    public string JobDetails {get; set;}
    public bool isDone {get; set;}
    public virtual User User {get; set;}
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

There are pretty good blog posts around, talking about this very specific topic. I'll give you a quick headsup on how and where to start.

I am taking John Attens example postes here as [reference](http://typecastexception.com/post/2013/11/11/Extending-Identity-Accounts-and-Implementing-Role-Based-Authentication-in-ASPNET-MVC-5.aspx).

Since you already have a `User` class, you can go right into your AccountController and implement an index method. You'd want to display all users first, so you can choose which one you want to delete.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var Db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var users = Db.Users;
    //ViewModel will be posted at the end of the answer
    var model = new List<EditUserViewModel>();
    foreach(var user in users)
    {
        var u = new EditUserViewModel(user);
        model.Add(u);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

From there you can implement the delete methods (GET and POST):

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Delete(string id = null)
{
    var Db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var user = Db.Users.First(u => u.UserName == id);
    var model = new EditUserViewModel(user);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(model);
}


[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
{
    var Db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var user = Db.Users.First(u => u.UserName == id);
    Db.Users.Remove(user);
    Db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

*EditUserViewModel*

```
public class EditUserViewModel
{
    public EditUserViewModel() { }

    // Allow Initialization with an instance of ApplicationUser:
    public EditUserViewModel(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        this.UserName = user.UserName;
        this.FirstName = user.FirstName;
        this.LastName = user.LastName;
        this.Email = user.Email;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    //you might want to implement jobs too, if you want to display them in your index view
}
```

*AGAIN: This is not my own code. It is an example written by John Atten at [http://typecastexception.com](http://typecastexception.com/). *