# ASP.NET MVC 5 Allows users to update their info

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm looking all over the place to find my answer, without success.

I am creating custom fields in the Identity aspnetuser table, this is working as it should, I can populate the fields upon registering.
The question now is, how can i allow my users to fill fields or even update them?

Do I do this in another table with normal LINQ statements, or can I use the aspnetUser table with customized fields? What is best practice?

Comment: Have you tried `yourContext.Users`?

Comment: No I haven't. Do you have Some reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the following classes that are in the project when it is created

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // Write any customer properties that you want here
    // as an example I am adding a property Name
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    { }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

You can modify any user in your controller like this:

**Code in Controller**

```
public ActionResult EditUser(string userId)
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var user = context.Users.Find(userId);
        user.Name = "Edited Name";
        context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I think you can get the basic idea from the above code and if you need something more then you can go to [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220835/how-to-crud-application-users-in-asp-net-mvc-5-with-scaffolding) to understand the basic `CRUD` with `ASP .NET Identity`.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what i needed!